# How can we deserialize JSON data to c# object from API response

Tags: c#, json, .net, object, serialization

I need to deserialize my json data. I am using Newtonsoft.Json for json operations. I tried a lot of method to deserialize this data but i failed. Btw, I need to summarize my system for better understanding. I am posting data every minute to an API. And its response to me. So I am trying to deserialize the response.

**What need I do to deserialize this json and use it like a normal c# object?** I want to deserialize **res** variable. Thank you for your interest.

*Here is the main code*

```
 var data = new SendData
            {
                Readtime = time,
                Stationid = new Guid(_stationid),
                SoftwareVersion = softwareVersion,
                Period = period,
                AkisHizi = akisHizi,
                AkisHizi_Status = status,
                AKM = akm,
                AKM_Status = status,
                CozunmusOksijen = cozunmusOksijen,
                CozunmusOksijen_Status = status,
                Debi = debi,
                Debi_Status = status,
                DesarjDebi = desarjDebi,
                DesarjDebi_Status = status,
                KOi = koi,
                KOi_Status = status,
                pH = ph,
                pH_Status = status,
                Sicaklik = sicaklik,
                Sicaklik_Status = status,
                Iletkenlik = iletkenlik,
                Iletkenlik_Status = status
            };

            var res = Services.sendData(data);

            MessageBox.Show(res.objects.ToString());
```

*Here is the services model PostData method*

```
 private ResultStatus<T> PostData<T>(string url, string data) where T : new()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                {

                    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    webClient.Headers.Add("AToken", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new AToken { TicketId = this.TicketId.ToString() }));

                    var resp = webClient.UploadString(this.Url + url, data);

                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultStatus<T>>(resp);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new ResultStatus<T>
                {
                    message = ex.Message + System.Environment.NewLine + url
                };
            }

        }
```

*Here is the sendData method*

```
public ResultStatus<object> sendData(SendData data)
        {

            var res = PostData<object>(this.stationType.ToString() + "/SendData", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));

            return res;

        }
```

Here is the MessageBox result (json data)

```
{ 
'Period': 1, 
'ReadTime': 
'2022-08-22714:01:00', 
'AKM': 65.73, 
'AKM_Status': 1,
'CozunmusOksijen': 0.2,
'CozunmusOksijen_Status': 1,
'Debi': 1.0,
'Debi_Status': 1,
'KOi': 25.1,
'KOi_Status': 1
}
```

Comment: Why are you using WebClient at all? That's an obsolete class replaced by HttpClient 10 years ago. And that's not an exaggeration - HttpClient was introduced in 2012. All supported .NET versions have it. JSON.NET works anyway, so it's unclear what the problem is here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this is not the correct answer.

Comment: You can reduce all of this code to just `var response= await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url,data);` and then read the payload with `var newdata=await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<MyPayload>();`. This won't help if the JSON response or URL is wrong though.

Comment: `this is not the correct answer.` this is not a correct question. You're asking people to help with a problem but never actually describe any problem. Did you get an exception? What does it *actually* say? It's not even clear whether JSON.NET is involved at all. Are you calling the wrong URL? Is the HTTP response *different* than your object?

Comment: Unless `stationType` is a *string* starting with a slash, or `this.Url` ends with a slash, `this.Url + url` will result in a bad URL. That's just one of the problems in the question's code that could cause it to fail. If you used the `Uri` class instead you'd get an error when combining the URL parts, not when making the actual call.

Comment: Apparently you didn't read the question. There is no code that doesn't work here, How can we deserialize the res object in the code. I just wanted support on this. Because I tried a lot of method and I failed. Thanks.

Comment: I did read the question, and found another critical error. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultStatus<object>>`. An `object` has no properties so you can't deserialize anything to it. The whole point of using generics is to provide the actual type without hard-coding it. You shouldn't be calling `Post<object>`, you should use the *expected* type.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is probably,

```
{ 
"Period": 1, 
"ReadTime": "2022-08-22T14:01:00", 
"AKM": 65.73, 
"AKM_Status": 1,
"CozunmusOksijen": 0.2,
"CozunmusOksijen_Status": 1,
"Debi2": 1.0,
"Debi_Status": 1,
"KOi": 25.1,
"KOi_Status": 1
}
```

From https://app.quicktype.io/, a C# model would be,

```
// <auto-generated />
//
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using QuickType;
//
//    var thing = Thing.FromJson(jsonString);

namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Thing
    {
        [JsonProperty("Period")]
        public long Period { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ReadTime")]
        public DateTimeOffset ReadTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AKM")]
        public double Akm { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AKM_Status")]
        public long AkmStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CozunmusOksijen")]
        public double CozunmusOksijen { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CozunmusOksijen_Status")]
        public long CozunmusOksijenStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Debi2")]
        public long Debi2 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Debi_Status")]
        public long DebiStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("KOi")]
        public double KOi { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("KOi_Status")]
        public long KOiStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Thing
    {
        public static Thing FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Thing>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Thing self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#how-to-read-json-as-net-objects-deserialize

```
 Thing? thing = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Thing>(res);
```

Comment: Let me try it, thanks for your help and interest.

Comment: I tried it but, when i write **res** in ( ) it says i know its funny but `1503: object to newtonsoft.json.reader` how can we solve it? thanks for your interest again

Comment: `Thing? thing = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Thing>(res);` this code still returns `1503: object to newtonsoft.json.reader` sorry about that..